# How can I put 3 separate programs into a JTabbedPane. They are already written for a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

So for the sake of keeping it simple, lets say I want to have 3 separate programs all display in a `JTabbedPane`. Suppose they are all Hello World simple file in a `JFrame`.

Lets use this simple file and create `HelloWorld1.java`, `HelloWorld2.java` and `HelloWorld3.java`. They exist separately this way. BUT say I want to combine them into ONE `JTabbedPane` - still keeping them separate. I am guessing I would need to create a project (lets say in Eclipse) and set up a `JTabbedPane` in a forth file and add these? Can someone give me a demonstration of this so I can understand clearer how to go about this. Appreciate any help. Just really interested in what the main (forth) file might look like.

Comment: Please post code to show what you have done and/or are struggling with, rather than asking for examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame child = new HelloWorld1("child1");
    child.add(new JLabel("Child1"));

    JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    jabbedPane.addTab("Child", child.getContentPane());

    child = new HelloWorld2("child2");
    jabbedPane.addTab("Child2", child.getContentPane());
    //and so on with other applications/frames

    JFrame main = new JFrame("Main");
    main.setSize(600,600);
    main.add(jTabbedPane);      
    main.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: +1 for reuse and using the content pane ;)

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple:

1) Instead of saying `public class HelloWorld1 extends JFrame{....}` use `public class HelloWorld1 extends JPanel{...}`

2) Instantiate your classes in main class (`HellowWorld1`,`HellowWorld2` and `HellowWorld3`) and add them to `JTabbedPane` like this:

```
HelloWorld1 hw = new HelloWorld1();
....
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.add("Title of first panel",hw);
```